# The request failed with HTTP 502

Tags: java, android, json, android-asynctask

While trying to run a `httppost` at my client (Android application) side using the below code, but on my browser, i do receive just the JSON output of the expected data.

```
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
                DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(new BasicHttpParams());
                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://192.168.43.229/thecee/mobile_app/the_lost.php");
                // Depends on your web service
              httppost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

                InputStream inputStream = null;
                String result = null;
                try {
                    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                    inputStream = entity.getContent();
                    // json is UTF-8 by default

                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8"), 8);
                   StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

                    String line = null;
                   while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
                    {
                        sb.append(line + "\n");
                        }
                   result = sb.toString();
                    Log.d("The Content", result);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                    // Oops
                    }
                finally{
                    try {
                        if (inputStream != null) inputStream.close();
                    } catch (Exception squish) {
                    }
                    }
                return result;
               }
```

I am getting the error message below while trying to parse it.

> 03-31 04:29:50.463 18871-19413/com.example.ji.thecce D/The Content:
>   
>                                                                          
>                                                                          http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'>
>                                                                          
>                                                                          The request failed
>
> Response Error.
>
> *Technical description:*
> 502 Bad Gateway - Response Error, a
>   bad response was received from another proxy server or the destination
>   origin server.
>
> 03-31 04:29:50.466 18871-18871/com.example.ji.thecce
>   W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: Value

I will sincerely appreciate your response.
Thanks for your time.

Comment: NOTE: for the webservice, this is the output {"result":[{"id":"1","student_id":"5013","subject1":"87","subject2":"87","subject3":"56","subject4":"76","subject5":"68","subject6":"58"},{"id":"2","student_id":"1234","subject1":"67","subject2":"77","subject3":"54","subject4":"78","subject5":"65","subject6":"45"}]}

Comment: Check weather the mobile and the server are on same network, also you can check the request response from the mobile by using [rest client for android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sn.restandroid&hl=en) to see it also receives **502** error

Comment: yes, i have been able to do that and they are on same network (server), cos i am also doing an authentication and registration which both work well, but the only part i am not getting is trying to do a listview by using that style. Thanks for your fast response